# How to prevent opening external app by change location.href in WKWebView?

Tags: swift, wkwebview

E.g. Aliexpress. If i have installed aliexpress app - it runs by clicking links on website, with javascript code: `location.href = aliexpress://.....`

I need open `app-scheme://` manually, by calling `UIApplication.shared.openURL()`, but not need auto-opening through WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load URLScheme for particular app you want to open when clicks occur on link.
More info you will get on [this url](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).

And if you want to prevent opening that app then monitor link click on this delegate method for WKWebView

```
decidePolicyForNavigationAction
```

**Edit:**

For intercepting any URL that is going to be open outside of application make a sublclass of UIApplication class and override OpenURL method. In this method you can check for URL and decide which URL you want to open outside of application.

Don't forget to assign you new class as Principal Class in the application.

Comment: In `decidePolicyForNavigationAction` i can not track the URL leading to an external application, initiated through javascript. Before opening the external application, I see in this method only the URL (with http:// scheme), which was clicked.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y6wAKAZC

do I understand correctly? But external application of WKWebView continues to open when you navigate the site. But `UIApplication.shared.openURL(externalAppURL)` works as expected:  displays the url in the console instead opening the app. WKWebView uses some other method to open URL in external application?

Comment: yes you understand correctly...so if you implement this then you don't need to worried about how WKWebView open external url...all url have to pass from that class.

Comment: But nevertheless, the external application continues opening in WKWebView despite the subclass of UIApplication :(

Comment: App opens in WKWebview?

Comment: In WKWebView on loaded webpage runs javascript: location.href = app-scheme:// and external application with url scheme "app-scheme://" open on my device.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably external URLs are thrown to **createWebViewWith Configuration:** method. 
Check this once, set your WKUIDelegate as self,

```
webview.UIDelegate = self
```

then implement the following delegate and handle the URL load properly,

```
public func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, createWebViewWith configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration, for navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures) -> WKWebView? 
    {
           //check the URL, either block it or handle it here.
            webView.load(navigationAction.request)
            return nil
    }
```

[Refer: Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkuidelegate/1536907-webview)